# Find a row in a data.table that is same as the header

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am reading in a huge csv file with `fread`. The data is somehow mis-formatted and the header is repeated now and then. I want now to remove the headers in the file, thus, I have to search for rows where the content is equal to the header.

I could think of 2 solutions, neither is optimal:

1. Option 1 assumes that all non-header repeating rows are otherwise mutually different in at least one position
2. Option 2 is very verbose and would require a lot of writing

Basically I would need a sort of a loop with loops through all columns and compare them with the header.

Thus, the whole thing boils down to the question:

*How to find a specific row in a data table **without** hard coding the filter?*

**Code**

```r
library(data.table)
foo <- data.frame(a = c(1:2, "a", 1:2, "a"), b = c(letters[1:2], "b", letters[2:1], "b"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
setDT(foo)

## option 1: use duplicates, assuming that each row is otherwise unique
foo[-(which(duplicated(rbind(as.list(names(foo)), foo))) - 1)]

## option 2: compare directly, but becomes very cumbersome with growing number of columns
foo[!(a == names(foo)[1] & b == names(foo)[2])]
```

Comment: Repeated headers are always same as the actual first header?

Comment: Yes from what I can tell

Comment: Then we only need to compare the first column, i.e. your option 2, but check only 1st column? Or remove headers outside R using grep, something like `fread("grep -v myCol1 myfile.txt")` ?

Comment: Interesting idea. I head the outside R option also in mind, but for reproducibility and documentation I'd like to have everything done in R. Looking only at the first (couple of) header(s) is interesting and smart and will work definitely for the existing data.

Comment: @thothal there is a way to pass commands like this from within R, just as showed by zx8754

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anti-join:

```
setkeyv(foo, names(foo)) # Reordes data though
foo[!list(names(foo))]

   a b
1: 1 a
2: 1 b
3: 2 a
4: 2 b
```

Without setting keys:

```
nfoo <- names(foo)
foo[!setNames(as.list(nfoo), nfoo), on = nfoo]
```

Comment: Nice and neat. Is it considered good practice though to set all columns as key, or do introduce some pitfalls later with this technique?

Comment: @thothal The only pitfall I can think of is that it reorders the data, anyway maybe best to avoid it. Posted a new possibility.

Answer (score 2):

As misplaced headers are repeated same as the actual headers, then we only need to compare the first column, i.e. your option 2, but check only 1st (or any) column:

```
foo[ !(a == names(foo)[1]), ]
```

Or remove headers outside R using grep, something like:

```
fread("grep -v myCol1 myfile.txt")
```

Or paste every row, compare with header:

```
foo[ do.call(paste, c(foo, list(sep = "_"))) != paste(colnames(foo), collapse = "_"), ]
```

I'd prefer to go with 2nd option, then we don't have issue of column classes that we have when using other "after-fread" solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as the data is alos otherwise misformatted I need to do some heavy data cleansing anyways. But I like the `grep` option. From your gut feeling, which solution is faster the `grep` one or the `anti_join` from sindri?

Comment: And for the `grep` I would change the `regex` to `^myCol1` hust to avoid that we filter out rows where `myCol1` appears legitimately.

Comment: @thothal my main concern is not speed but column classes getting messed up, I'd grep clean then let fread fix my column classes. Gut feeling: grep might win.

Comment: @thothal yes grep is just an example, you need to test what regex works best for your real data.

Comment: This is very interesting. Will it work on any machine?

Comment: UNderstood, but column classes are anyways messed up in my case.  In general I agree to have clean col classes to start with, but no chance here.